# SQL Quickest way to determine if a multiple columns have had a non zero value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Background:
I have a table that currently receives a row of data from around 100 sites per day, 365 days a year.  The number of sites is increasing around 13 sites per month.  I am looking for a long term solution.

The structure is:

```
id:int
site:int
created:datetime
dept_a:decimal(12,2)
dept_b:decimal(12,2)
...
dept_y:decimal(12,2)
dept_z:decimal(12,2)
```

The problem:

I would like to know if there has ever been a non zero entry in EACH of the **dept_x** columns for each of the **site**s.

There is a server timeout of 30 seconds, and although my current solution of

```
if(sum(dept_x)>0,1,0) as dept_x_used, if(sum(dept_y)>0,1,0) as dept_y_used, ...
```

currently works, and works pretty quickly, the system I am building needs to support more sites and still search back to see if the dept_x has ever has a non zero.

My concern is that as the amount of data being searched is growing constantly, as well as the amount of new daily data increasing.

If possible, doing it right from the start would be better that bodging, then having to come back later to fix it when it becomes too slow.

I am also open to alternative ways to handle this such as a separate table that stores information related to the column ever having had a non zero value.

Some sample data:

```
1, 1, 2016-03-01, 53.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 30.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, ...
2, 7, 2016-03-01, 26.00, 15.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, ...
3, 6, 2016-03-01, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 23.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, ...
4, 2, 2016-03-01, 14.00, 6.00, 0.00, 0.00, 13.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, ...
5, 2, 2016-03-02, 55.00, 0.00, 32.00, 0.00, 18.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, ...
6, 4, 2016-03-02, 3.00, 0.00, 4.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, ...
```

In this case the output would be something like

```
site dept_a_used dept_b_used dept_c_used dept_d_used dept_e_used
1    1           0           0           0           1
2    1           1           1           0           1
4    1           0           1           0           0
6    0           0           0           0           1
7    1           0           0           0           0
```

The purpose is to determine if a department code has ever been used on a site before, so that we can verify that the monthly report contains all of the departments that have ever been used.  All of our other reports have a descriptor such a 'monthly report for ALL departments' or 'monthly reports for SELECTED departments' however this report does not differentiate, and we have no control over the reports when they are generated, we can only check them and report back if they do not contain the correct departments.

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, I have added some data and an explanation of why I am trying to do this.

Comment: The `dept_x` pattern bugs me because it sounds like a normal form violation -- can you change that? Anyways, if you could narrow your query by adding a date in the `WHERE` clause and create an index with it, you'll be good to go.

Comment: Hi Rubens, I can change that if required - a day or 2 to update the scripts and templates that rely on it, however I am happy to do that if required.  What would the alternative be to avoid a normal form violation?  I have tried to normalize most of the data structures however this is the most normal I could come up with for this table.

Comment: You would transform every column `dept_x` column into a row in another table, so your structure would be (id, site, dept, created, value); then you can do a `JOIN` between those tables and identify what departments do not have any rows with values

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not an expert in programming and in english too, but I may have an idea for you.

Why don't you store an information on your row of data which say "This row has already been checked" => 1 or "This row hasn't been checked yet" => 0.

If you don't have to recheck a row which has been check one-time, you can do that and then do your verification only on rows which have the "0" information on your new col. In this way the amount of data will be smaller than checking every row.

I wish I understand your problem and it can help you.

Arnaud

Comment: Maybe that indicator isn't the only use for the column value

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're telling, in my answer I mean adding a new column to the table where values have to be checked, and on this new column store an information which say if the row have already been checked or not.